# What permissions does user need to have to use linked server and its default remote user mapping

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have some LinkedServer and for it created default mapping that `mapping list` is empty, and all goes thru 'Be made using this security context' and this works fine.

I can query this linked from any user that have `sysadmin` role
but when I have user that is `public` only then I get an error:

> There is no mapping for user x

How can I fix that? Is there some special permission that I need to apply? This is for SQL Server 2019.

Scripted linked is:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
            @server = N'PB01_ENC', @srvproduct=N'', 
            @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'x.x.x.x,9945'
            @provstr=N'Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
            @rmtsrvname=N'PB01_ENC',
            @useself=N'False',
            @locallogin=NULL,
            @rmtuser=N'xxx',@rmtpassword='########'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
            @server=N'PB01_ENC', 
            @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
```

others  linked but not encrypted works fine.

Am I missing something here maybe?

Please advice

Even if I add specific mapping for this public user - with password or via impersonate - still the same :/

I do not want to add this user  sa permissions and need to exec remote query on it

Comment: Aside... you should move away from `SQLNCLI` aka. `SNAC` aka. SQL Server Native Client as soon as possible. It hasn't received any feature updates since SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft has **finally** [removed it from SQL Server 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client).

Comment: thx i didnt known - do You think this could handle this case if i replace it?

Comment: Well, does the remote user exists? Note that you cannot use AD logins, only SQL Logins, at least i never managed to get it to work

Comment: Yes it exists as it woths when user is SA -if it would not exists then even as sa it would not work

Comment: Yes perms are ok. if it would be not then it would not work when user is sa group. if i script the linked AS the non sa user then it does not see this part @provstr=N'Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;' and also does not see the EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'PB01_ENC',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'xxx',@rmtpassword='########' part . so guess this is the issue here somehow